# Manage a secondary window/task

Tags: c++, qt, window

I am building an application that has several stages to create and combine various text files.

The main program code implements the various stages one of which, in the middle of the process, displays a secondary window and has the user select items listed in checkboxes.

The selections are made in batches of ten records. When all the selections have been made, the main program is to continue and produce the final text file.

My code calls `showNextBatch()` to display the checkbox selections as a `QWidget`. A signal/slot calls a second function `onNextBatchButtonClicked()` to save the selections and reset the counters for the next batch of records.

These functions loop until all the records have been processed.

I thought that the main program would hand control to the two functions until the latter had exhausted the available records.

I have output statements in both:

- `showNextbatch`:

  ```
  cout << "97 Saved selected contact listings to retain.csv" << endl;
  ```
- The main program:

  ```
  cout << "98 All new contact listings have been processed" << endl;
  ```

Which, if my logic was correct, would display in this order:

```
"97"
"98"
```

However, the "**98**" line is displayed immediately after calling `showNextbatch` for the first time.

Note that, in the following application Output, the "**97**" message is displayed after all the batches have been processed, but the "**98**" message occurs much earlier, i.e. after the first instance of "Running `showNextBatch`".

```
20:43:36: Starting /home/toaster/qt/UpdateContacts...
Created retain.csv
Setup counters
jstart = 0
jend = 9
jmax = 15
Running showNextBatch
jstart = 0
jend = 9
jmax = 15
98 All new contact listings have been processed
Opened retain.csv in append mode
Running showNextBatch
jstart = 10
jend = 15
jmax = 15
Opened retain.csv in append mode
Running showNextBatch
jstart = 16
jend = 15
jmax = 15
97 Saved selected contact listings to retain.csv
20:43:49: /home/toaster/qt/UpdateContacts exited with code 0
```

The problem is that stage 3 cannot be started until stage 2 has been completed and it appears that the main program code is happy to continue to run even while the functions are still looping.

How to have the checkbox selection process complete and then have the main program continue with its tasks?

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVector>
#include <QCheckBox>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_startButton_clicked();
    void on_closeButton_clicked();
    void showNextBatch();
    void onNextBatchButtonClicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QList<QString> diffs;
    int j, jstart, jend, jmax;
    QWidget* SelectBy10;
    QVector<QCheckBox*> checkboxes; // QVector to store checkboxes

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QListWidgetItem>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QCheckBox>

using namespace std;


// =============================================================
// Testing processing records in batches of ten
// =============================================================


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_closeButton_clicked()
{
    // Close main program window
    close();
}

void MainWindow::showNextBatch()
{
    cout << "Running showNextBatch" << endl;
    cout << "jstart = " << jstart << endl;
    cout << "jend = " << jend << endl;
    cout << "jmax = " << jmax << endl;

    if (jstart < jmax)
    {
        // Display the batch of records for selection of any
        // that the user checks to be retained

        SelectBy10 = new QWidget();
        QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();

        for (j = jstart; j <= jend; ++j)
        {
            QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox(diffs[j]);
            checkboxes.append(checkbox);
            layout->addWidget(checkbox);
        }

        QPushButton* nextButton = new QPushButton("Next page");
        layout->addWidget(nextButton);
        SelectBy10->setLayout(layout);
        SelectBy10->setWindowTitle("Retain Selected Contacts");
        SelectBy10->show();

        // Connect the nextButton to the slot to show the next batch

        connect(nextButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onNextBatchButtonClicked);

    } else {

        // All batches have been processed

        cout << "97 Saved selected contact listings to retain.csv" << endl;
        ui->listWidget->addItem("97 Saved selected contact listings to retain.csv");

        return;

    }

}

void MainWindow::onNextBatchButtonClicked()
{
    // Save the checked checkboxes

    QFile retainFile("retain.csv");
    if (!retainFile.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open retain.csv" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    QTextStream retain(&retainFile);
    cout << "Opened retain.csv in append mode" << endl;
    // Iterate through the checkboxes
    for (j = jstart; j <= jend; ++j)
    {
        if (checkboxes[j]->isChecked())
        {
            QString text = checkboxes[j]->text();
            retain << text << "\n"; // Write the text to the CSV file
        }
    }
    // Close retain.csv

    retainFile.close();

    // Close the current batch window

    SelectBy10->close();

    // Update the counters for the next batch

    jstart = jend + 1;
    jend = jstart + 9;
    if (jend > jmax) jend = jmax;

    // Show the next batch of contacts

    showNextBatch();
}

// =============================================================
// MainWindow
// =============================================================

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()

{
    // Add entry to the QlistWidget progress log

    ui->listWidget->addItem("");
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget->addItem("Processing...");

    // =====================================================================
    // Display the different contact listings in batches of ten, allowing
    // the user to select those that are to be stored in retain.csv and
    // sunsequently added to address_master.csv
    // =====================================================================

    // Create the file retain.csv which will subsequently be opened in append mode
    // in order to add new listings as batches of contacts are processed

    QFile retainFile("retain.csv");
    retainFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream retain(&retainFile);
    cout << "Created retain.csv" << endl;
    retainFile.close();

    // Note that the diffs array and the counters j, jstart, jend, and jmax
    // have been declared in mainwindow.h

    // Create a dummy diffs array with 14 records

    cout << "Setup counters" << endl;
    j = 0, jstart = 0, jend = 9, jmax = 15;
    cout << "jstart = " << jstart << endl;
    cout << "jend = " << jend << endl;
    cout << "jmax = " << jmax << endl;

    for (j = jstart; j <= jmax; ++j)
    {
        diffs.append("Diff " + QString::number(j)); // Add elements to the list
    }

    // Establish the line counters, determine imax as the number of contact listings
    // to be processed, then set the end value for the loop counter as one less than
    // jmax since, in the loop, diffs 1-10 are counted as j = 0-9

    jstart = 0;
    jend = 9;
    jmax = diffs.size() - 1;

    // Process the new contact listings in batches of ten

    showNextBatch();

    // Follow-up after all batches processed

    cout << "98 All new contact listings have been processed" << endl;
    ui->listWidget->addItem("98 All new contact listings have been processed");

    return;

}
```

Comment: *"the main program code is happy to continue to run even while the functions are still looping. Clearly, there is something fundamental about Qt c++ that I don't understand. "* Yeah, the main event loop must never stop running, because that freezes the UI. Functions should never keep looping for more than (ideally) about 18 milliseconds at a time, or at least no more than about 200 milliseconds.

Comment: Not sure but it sounds like you want your second window `SelectBy10` to be a modal dialog.

Comment: @G.M. A modal dialogue box was required so I'm now working on a version of the code that will use:
SelectBy10Dialog selectBy10; 
selectBy10.setModal(true); 
selectBy10.exec();